# Disable Days in Jquery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, date, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar as a large date picker with added features, and need to disable all Sundays and various other days throughout the year. Jquery UI date picker allows you to create methods for disabling dates. Is there a similar setup for FullCalendar?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I needed a hybrid that shows events and allows for date picking with "disabled" Sundays and dates from a string, like the jQuery UI date picker. With some hacking I got what I needed. The only drawback being each time the "back" and "forward" buttons are clicked the entire calender must be re-rendered rather than reusing existing elements like in the standard script.

Its still a work in progress and only implemented for the month view, but here is the gist: http://gist.github.com/361248

Thanks for replying.

Comment: Hey man, this looks great. Did you go about finishing this, or add it to the fullCalendar repo? I think many would like to see this kind of functionality in fullCalendar! I know I do! I'm about to try this out. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

b/c fullcalendar is not a datepicker (days cant be "selected"), there really is no notion of 'disabling' a day. if you don't want any events on a given day, simply filter your event data.

Comment: Yeah, I needed a hybrid that shows events and allows for date picking with "disabled" Sundays and dates from a string, like the jQuery UI date picker. With some hacking I got what I needed. The only drawback being each time the "back" and "forward" buttons are clicked the entire calender must be re-rendered rather than reusing existing elements like in the standard script.

Its still a work in progress and only implemented for the month view, but here is the gist: http://gist.github.com/361248

Thanks for replying.

Comment: has disabled dates been added now? It seems fullcalendar now can "select" days http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/

Comment: Just for the record you can now select the days so this answer maybe good for older versions

Answer (score 0):

Use hiddenDays:[0]
above line hide Sundays from the Calendar. hiddendays take array of integer values. 0 represents Sunday, 1 represents Monday and so on. if you have to hide Saturday and Sunday use 
hiddenDays:[0,6]