# Disable Selectable for Specific Days in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Is there a way to disable specific days from being selected in the Jquery FullCalendar?
I'm trying to disable days that have already been booked or are in process in a booking calendar for a rental house.

Answer (score 0):

Check the comment to this question already answered here : [Disable Days in Jquery FullCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479165/disable-days-in-jquery-fullcalendar)

Seems userX found a workaround, perhaps you can try/adapt his code ?